# SAPUI5 - sap.m.Table with factory functions not showing columns and items

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement wherein I have to populate columns and rows dynamically from oData. For test purpose I created the following JSON files for columns and rows.

```
column.json    

{
    "Columns":  [
        { "column": "col1" },
        { "column": "col2" },
        { "column": "col3" }
    ]
}


row.json

{
    "Rows":  [
        { "col1": "abc",
          "col2": "def",
          "col3": "ghi"
        },
        { "col1": "jkl",
          "col2": "mno",
          "col3": "pqr"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my view

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
        controllerName="sam.test" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Table id="ID" 
        columns="{path: 'Column>/Columns', factory: '.populateColumns'}"
        items="{path: 'Row>/Rows', factory: '.populateItems'}">
    </Table></core:View>
```

Note that in manifest file "Column" points to column.json and "Row" points to row.json file.

Here is my corresponding controller -

```
sap.ui.controller("sam.test", {

//  onInit: function() {
//  },


//  onBeforeRendering: function() {
//
//  },

//  onAfterRendering: function() {
//
//  },

//  onExit: function() {
//
//  }


    populateItems: function(sId, oContext) {
        var row = new sap.m.ColumnListItem(sId, {
            type: "Active",
            cell: [
                   new Text({
                       text: "{Column>col1}"
                   }),
                   new Text({
                       text: "{Column>col2}"
                   }),
                   new Text({
                       text: "{Column>col3}"
                   })
            ]
        });

        return row;
    },

    populateColumns: function(sId, oContext) {
        var sColumnId = oContext.getObject().column;

        return new sap.ui.table.Column({
            id: sColumnId,
            label: sColumnId,
            template: sColumnId,
            sortProperty: sColumnId,
            filterProperty: sColumnId
        });
    }

});
```

This however is not working. It renders table with no column headers and no rows. When I bind rows directly to items aggregation of Table and also provide columns aggregation with same value it works.

Am I missing something? I am having tough time figuring this out. Any pointers will be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 Mistakes which I found:

1. Wrong type of Column: new sap.ui.table.Column- The correct column type should be **sap.m.Column** since this is a sap.m.Table.
2. Wrong name of aggregation used for sap.m.ColumnListItem: The correct aggregation is **cells** and **not** **cell** ( typo).
3. Wrong model is bound to ColumnListItem: It should be **Row>col1** and **not** **Column>col1** as Row model stores the data.

Lets correct these mistakes and below is the working code:

```
 populateItems: function(sId, oContext) {
            var row = new sap.m.ColumnListItem(sId, {
                type: "Active",
                cells: [
                       new sap.m.Text({
                           text: "{Row>col1}"
                       }),
                       new sap.m.Text({
                           text: "{Row>col2}"
                       }),
                       new sap.m.Text({
                           text: "{Row>col3}"
                       })
                ]
            });

            return row;
        },

        populateColumns: function(sId, oContext) {
            var sColumnId = oContext.getObject().column;

            return new sap.m.Column({
              header: new sap.m.Text({
                  text:'{Column>column}'
              })
            });
        },
```

Let me know if this works.

[image]